# Как проверить массив на условия в одну строчку?

Tags: c++

У меня есть массив который имеет значение true и false

Инициализация

```
 const int numb = 3;
 bool time[numb]{};

 for (int i = 0; i < numb; ++i) {
  time[i] = тут карочи длинный код, он не важен, он выдает true то false, зависит от номера цикла и условия.

  // теперь что меня интересует, я делаю сейчас так, мне не очень удобно
  if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true && time[2]  == true) {
      std::cout << i << " - i | " << " PFF " << "\n" << std::endl;
  }
  // я не могу сделать так, потому что мне нужно проверить все данные одновременно в каждом цикле.
  if(time[i]) {
      std::cout << i << " - i | " << " PFF 2 " << "\n" << std::endl;
  }
 
  // еще интересует проверка по последовательности, типа проверять по началу все, потом на одну меньше потом еще на одну меньше и так до конца.
  // например это выглядит так
  if(проверить вначале 3 значения, потом 2, потом 1) {
      std::cout << i << " - i | " << " PFF 3 " << "\n" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

В принципе это все, интересует только как коротко проверить все в условии if а не писать простыню кода, особенно если цифра будет больше 3.

Вот что я имею введу под последовательностью вложенности, я сделал пример основываясь на `const int numb = 2` а то если будет `3` это уже слишком много, можно запутаться сейчас.

```
    if(time[0] == false && time[1]  == true) {
        std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 1 " << "\n" << std::endl;
        
        time[1] = false;

    }
    else if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == false) {
        std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 4 " << "\n" << std::endl;
       
        time[0] = false;
    }
    else if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true) {
        
        std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 0 " << "\n" << std::endl;
       
        time[1] = false; // или time[0] = false

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимум два варианта:

- `std::all_of(std::begin(time), std::end(time), [](bool x){return x;})`, или
- `std::find(std::begin(time), std::end(time), false) == std::end(time)`.

Это лучше сделать один раз перед циклом, и сохранить результат в булевую переменную.

Еще, вот это:

```
int numb = 3;
bool time[numb]{};
```

- не валидный C++. Или делайте `const int numb = 3;` (если размер известен во время компиляции), или меняйте массив на вектор: `std::vector<bool> time(3);`.

Comment: Да вроде ничего так, а можно еще проверка по последовательности?

Comment: const int numb поправил в описание

Comment: @donifrok Не понял про последовательность.

Comment: это будет выглядеть так
`if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true && time[2]  == true)` если сработало то следующая будет проверка такая
`if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true)` еще раз сработала то такая
`if(time[0] == true)`
и так по кругу

Comment: @donifrok Если правильно понял, то надо `std::end(time)` заменить на `std::end(time) - i`.

Comment: не не помогло -i чет дич какая та получается
и у вас ошибка в коде, где `(bool x}' должно быть `(bool x)
еще мне чет не получается запустить find, наверно библиотека нужна.

Comment: @donifrok Скобочку поправил. Да, действительно нужен инклуд; задание: нагуглить документацию на функцию, выяснить какой инклуд нужен. Если `- i` не сработал, покажите два примера кода: с ним, и как бы вы без него написали.

Comment: добавил пример про последовательность, если бы делал без вашего кода

Comment: все отредактировал.

Comment: @donifrok Какой-то мутный пример. Вы понимаете, что ни в один из 4 вложенных if-ов выполнение никогда не зайдет? И все это эквивалентно `if (time[0] != time[1]) time[0] = time[1] = false;`?

Comment: Я сам запутался на секунду, там еще нужно было кусок добавить

Comment: Возможно стоит другой вопрос задать

Comment: @donifrok Стоит. Вы только с мыслями соберитесь сначала. Еще if-ы, который вы сейчас добавили, страдают той же проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

Т.е. вам просто нужно убедиться, что ВСЕ значения массива `time[]` истинны?

Что-то типа

```
if (all_of(begin(time),end(time),[](bool t) { return t;}))
```

вас устроит?

Можно и так:

```
if (!any_of(begin(time),end(time),[](bool t) { return !t;}))
```

Comment: А почему второй может быть быстрее?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Потому что при *разумной* реализации при первом же встреченном `false` должен прекратить работу. Хотя да, `all_of` в принципе тоже должен обломиться на первом же неподходящем, согласен, поспешил...

Comment: можно еще проверка по последовательности?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы под этим понимаете, и чего именно хотите достичь.

Comment: это будет выглядеть так if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true && time[2]  == true) если сработало то следующая будет проверка такая if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true) еще раз сработала то такая if(time[0] == true) и так по кругу

Comment: Ну, если уж сработала первая, то сработают и остальные. Так какой в этом смысл? Просто же проверка от 0 до i-го — `if (all_of(time,time+i,[](bool t) { return t;}))`

Comment: Кстати, ваш псевдокод охватывает только 3 случая. Точно в остальных 5 случаях ничего не должно выполняться? :)

Comment: Я добавил пример что бы я хотел, если бы не использовал ваш кода

Comment: Что вы хотите, понять не могу. Но я бы использовал в любом случае битовое представление, и работал с чем-то типа `int` — вот и массив до 32 элементов :), да и все операции выглядят куда проще. А что вы хотите — ни из этого вопроса, ни из нового — я понять не могу...