# Как упростить проверить условия на истину с несколькими значениями?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, шаблоны-с++, c++20

Я думаю что это походе чем то на код грея где все условия проверяются и исполняются последовательно, но с одним условием, нельзя повторять то что уже исполнилось.

По сути я ожидаю когда весь массив заполниться и код начинает проверку по условиям, единственное я не могу остановить цикл поэтому проверки должны учитывать это.

Вот что я хочу упростить

```
        if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 0 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[1] = false;
        }

        else if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == false) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 1 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[0] = false;
        }
        else if(time[0] == false && time[1]  == true) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 2 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[1] = false;
        }
```

Я тут использовал только 2 значения в массиве, но будет еще такое, где массив размером 3

```
        if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true && time[2]  == true) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 0 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[2] = false;
        }
        else if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == true && time[2]  == false) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 1 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[1] = false;
        }
        else if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == false && time[2]  == false) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 2 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[0] = false;
        }
        else if(time[0] == false && time[1]  == false && time[2]  == true) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 3 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[2] = false;
        }
        else if(time[0] == false && time[1]  == true && time[2]  == false) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 4 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[1] = false;
        }
        else if(time[0] == false && time[1]  == true && time[2]  == true) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 5 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[2] = false;
        }
        else if(time[0] == true && time[1]  == false && time[2]  == true) {

            std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) 6 " << "\n" << std::endl;
            time[0] = false;
        }
```

Я кстати не уверен что правильно написал второй вариант, но вроде все учтено.

Полный код на эксперименты https://godbolt.org/z/vMsTWfe4x

Comment: `== true` не нужен. `== false` меняется на отрицание.

Comment: вложенности тут никакой нет, подправьте заголовок. Тут всего лишь несколько условий.

Comment: посмотрите этот вопрос (ваш кстати), возможно там уже есть ответ. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429910/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83?rq=1

Comment: @n1tr0xs это тоже мой вопрос :), просто я продолжил его отдельно, по сколько там ответ уже дан на главный вопрос.

Comment: Обычный детерминированный конечный автомат, нет?

Comment: @Harry ну да есть сходства, но функция эта нужна для других целей :)

Comment: ДКА не цель, а средство...

Comment: @Harry не понял, ну ладно

Comment: В примере прослеживается логика: вы всегда сбрасываете старший из флагов, установленный в true.  Исключение только для `time[0] == true && time[1]  == false && time[2]  == true`. Опечатка или я неверно восстановил логику?

Comment: @Chorkov эта не опечатка, это я специально так сделал, но если у вас функция делает тоже самое придерживаясь одной логике, то это тоже подойдет.
Изначально я так и задумывал, изменять по началу последние значении потом в обратную сторону первые значения.
Потом передумал и сделал все вручную, без какого то определенного алгоритма.

Comment: Тогда, возможно, есть логика и для числа печатаемого в ` " XD :)  ... `? или достаточно чтобы это были уникальные номера для каждой комбинации флагов?

Comment: @Chorkov то что он печатает это не важно, хоть будет печатать тоже самое, я добавил счетчик что бы видеть разницу вызовов, ну и указал номер для каждого значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const size_t bad_index = ~ size_t(0);

template<unsigned Size>
size_t lastFlagIndex( const bool (&array) [Size] )
{
    // Можно сделать тоже с помощью стандартных алгоритмов. Но ненужно: вас это пока запутает.
    for(size_t i=0;  i<Size; ++i)
        if( array[ Size-i-1 ] )
             return Size-i-1;
    return bad_index ; // Если ни один флаг не установлен - возвращаем заведомо неверное значений флага.
}


template<unsigned Size>
size_t flagsToBinaryValue( const bool (&array) [Size] )
{
     size_t ret=0;
     for(bool f: array)
          ret = ret *2 + (f?1:0);
     return ret;
}

....
// Вместо цепочки if-else:
            if( lastFlagIndex(time)!=bad_index )
            {
                std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) " << flagsToBinaryValue(time) << "\n" << std::endl;
                time [ lastFlagIndex(time) ] = false;
            }
```

Comment: Пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: "Можно сделать тоже с помощью стандартных алгоритмов," 
Можно пример тоже со стандартным алгоритмом, максимально сжатая версию можно, я разберусь если там мало кода, через F12

Comment: а что значит символ `~` вот тут `bad_index = ~ size_t(0);` я первый раз такой вижу

Comment: @donifrok `~` - это битовый НЕ. Т.е.  поскольку число ` size_t(0)` состоит из одних нулей в своем двоичном представлении, то получим число, которое состоит из одних единиц, в двоичном представлении. Т.е. максимально возможное значение для size_t.

Comment: А можно как то в обратную сторону этот алгоритм сделать?
Все тоже самое только с другой стороны.

Answer (score 1):

Две таблицы. `xds` по трём булевым индексам возвращает значение `xd` для печати. `clear` по трём булевым индексам возвращает какую переменную стереть:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    //        xd
    // ttt -> 0 -> ttf
    // ttf -> 1 -> tff
    // tff -> 2 -> fff
    // fft -> 3 -> fff
    // ftf -> 4 -> fff
    // ftt -> 5 -> ftf
    // tft -> 6 -> fft

    const int xds[2][2][2] = {
        {{-1, 3}, {4, 5}},
        {{ 2, 6}, {1, 0}},
    };

    const int clear[2][2][2] = {
        {{-1, 2}, {1, 2}},
        {{ 0, 0}, {1, 2}},
    };

    bool time[3] = {true, true, true};

    for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {

        int xd = xds[time[0]][time[1]][time[2]];
        if (xd < 0) {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) " << xd << '\n';
        time[clear[time[0]][time[1]][time[2]]] = false;
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror table.cpp && ./a.out
> 0 - i |  XD :) 0
> 1 - i |  XD :) 1
> 2 - i |  XD :) 2
> ```

Ещё один вариант с двумя таблицами. Теперь таблицы - одномерные массивы. Индекс в них строится из массива `time`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    //        xd
    // ttt -> 0 -> ttf
    // ttf -> 1 -> tff
    // tff -> 2 -> fff
    // fft -> 3 -> fff
    // ftf -> 4 -> fff
    // ftt -> 5 -> ftf
    // tft -> 6 -> fft

    const int xds[] = {
        -1, // 0b000
         3, // 0b001
         4, // 0b010
         5, // 0b011
         2, // 0b100
         6, // 0b101
         1, // 0b110
         0  // 0b111
    };

    const int clear[] = {
        -1, // 0b000 
         2, // 0b001 
         1, // 0b010 
         2, // 0b011 
         0, // 0b100 
         0, // 0b101 
         1, // 0b110 
         2  // 0b111 
    };

    bool time[3] = {true, true, true};

    for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
        int j = 0;
        for (bool t : time) {
            j = 2 * j + static_cast<int>(t);
        }

        int xd = xds[j];
        if (xd < 0) {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) " << xd << '\n';
        time[clear[j]] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример. 
А если массив будет больше 3, я просто думаю у меня будут разные значение массива time[] от 2 и выше.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Не понял ваш вопрос. Если менять размер `time`, надо будет менять таблицы и код, который к ним обращается. Объём самого кода почти не изменится.

Comment: Можете пример показать как вы это делаете с разным размером массива.
Просто у вас довольно сложный код, как мне кажется, хотя это дело времени что бы понять как работает он.

Comment: Я примерно понял как это работает, но путаница будет постоянно с этими таблицами, сама идея таблиц хорошая, однако такие сложные концепции как это `time[clear[time[0]][time[1]][time[2]]]` убивают все понимание, у меня просто в мозгу оперативки не хватает.
Я представляю какие сложности будет с таблицей `xds[2][2][2][2]`

Comment: @donifrok, добавил вариант с одномерными таблицами.

Answer (score 1):

> @Harry не понял, ну ладно

Ну, чтоб было понятнее... Ваши переходы между состояниями выглядят так (возле стрелок — то, что выводится, состояния — `time[0]time[1]time[2]`):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, я бы использовал не массив `bool`, а просто какой-то `unsigned` с соответствующими битовыми представлениями...

И получается весь ваш код со всеми if'ами —

```
struct DKA
{
    int value;
    unsigned char next;
} dka[8] = {
    { 0xFF, 0xFF },
    { 3, 0 }, { 4, 0 },
    { 5, 2 }, { 2, 0 },
    { 6, 1 }, { 1, 4 },
    { 0, 6 } };


unsigned char step(unsigned char t, int i)
{
    if (dka[t].next == 0xFF) return t;
    std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) " << dka[t].value << '\n';
    return dka[t].next;
}
```

Если ну очень нужно через массив — что-то типа

```
unsigned char x = (time[0]<<2)|(time[1]<<1)|time[0];
x = step(x,i);
time[2] = x&1;
time[1] = x&2;
time[0] = x&4;
```

Собственно, вот и весь код.

Ах, да!

[Программа полностью](https://ideone.com/w9YBNI) — аналог той, что на https://godbolt.org/z/vMsTWfe4x ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const int numb = 5;

struct DKA
{
    int value;
    unsigned char next;
} dka[8] = {
    { 0xFF, 0xFF }, { 3, 0 }, { 4, 0 },
    { 5, 2 }, { 2, 0 }, { 6, 1 },
    { 1, 4 }, { 0, 6 } };


unsigned char step(unsigned char t, int i)
{
    if (dka[t].next == 0xFF) return t;
    std::cout << i << " - i | " << " XD :) " << dka[t].value << '\n';
    return dka[t].next;
}

int main()
{

    unsigned char time = 0;

    for (int h = 0; h < 20; ++h)
    {
        time = 0x07;
        for (int i = 0, z = 0, n = 0; i < 10; ++i, ++n, ++z)
        {
            std::cout << n << " - n | " << i << " - i | " << " run " << std::endl;
            time = step(time,i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за код, попозже попробую разобраться как работает, сейчас уже поздно.